# I can't change or add anything, sudo not working...sudo: can't open /etc/sudoers: Permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu, permissions, sudo

I'm trying to install Ruby on Rails and I was using SSH to login to the linux machine, when I started working, everything was fine and I'm sure there was a mistake I made where the file/directory permissions changed.

Now when I try to send a command like:

```
sudo apt-get install rubygems
```

I get this error:

```
sudo: can't open /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
```

Not sure what to do next, what options do I have. I can login as root user as well but I don't want to dig a deeper hole for myself.

The linux machine is running on Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
chmod -R 0440 /etc/sudoers.d
```

may be you changed the permissions by mistake.

Comment: explain it, details

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked whether the file /etc/sudoers exists or whether the permissions have changes ?

This question may be better suited to the Linux/Ubuntu (or whatever flavour of Linux you have).

See:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu